# Can you define the parameters of a Apache Commons Command Line to feed to a method?

Tags: java, command-line

I have been recently running JUnit on some code and ran across an issue that I haven't been able to figure it out.

The application is run in Linux and therefore uses Apache Commons CLI.

In the code that i am testing, i ran across this method, code has been generalized

```
public void processCmdl (CommandLine cmdl) throws Exception
```

I also came across

```
public CommandLine getCmdLine() {return this.commandLine}
```

In my testing, both of these return Null to my tests and cause the tests to fail with null pointer exception errors.

My question is, is there anyway to define the parameters of the CommandLine object? so that it can be passed to the methods or defined in them so that they can be returned?  The methods will then process the CommandLine using Options and Parsers.

I know that the main(String[] args) uses a String[] to handle the arguments from the command Line.

I just want to see if there was anyway to define parameters of the CommandLine ie.

```
java run.jar -p param.....
```

so that when the Command line object is read, there are no null values that kick the tests out.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Use a mocking framework to mock the object? What's the issue exactly?

Comment: Hi Boris, I forgot to add a few circumstances, sorry. There are circumstances that prohibit me from downloading extra software, so i was curious if there was anyway, other than mocking frameworks, that would allow me to emulate the command line.